# How to add HTML to JS append. method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, liferay-6.2

I have a little problem, because I don't know how to insert a LifeRay message to the JavaScript CONTENT. It works very nice, but only when text is provided. I want to view the UI message in another div which was previously generated by Liferay with id=p_86. I simply have to put tag liferay-ui:success into above div. This event is related to data saving. It works good but the message is displayed in the wrong place so I want to move it to div with id=p_68.

```
<liferay-ui:success key="klucz" message="
    <%=PortletUtils.getInfoMessage(renderRequest) %>"/>
<liferay-ui:error key="cap_global_msg_error_key" message="
    <%=PortletUtils.getErrorMessage(renderRequest) %>"/>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#p_86").append("<div id='newid'> CONTENT </div>");
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an element in your DOM with the id "p_86" ? Try changing .append to .appendChild

Comment: append() works with text, DOM objects, or jQuery objects. Just get a reference to your liferay element and append that, eg `append( $('#LifeRayElementId') )`

Comment: @SPlatten, appendChild is a DOM method, jQuery objects do not have a method called appendChild

Comment: @PatrickEvans, yes, I realised that after posting, thank you, question regarding the ID still stands.

Comment: After what event you wanna do this? please update your question.

Comment: I have an element which is div with id=p_86.